# In a metric space, is every open set the countable union of closed sets?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In a metric space, it is true that every open set can be represented as the union of closed sets (e.g. the union of closed balls).

I am wondering if every open set can be represented as the countable union of closed sets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say $U$ is an open set. If $U$ is empty or if it is the whole space $X$ then $U$ is also closed, so we are done. Now assume that $U$ and its complement $U^c=X\setminus U$ are both non-empty.

Let $A_n = \bigcup_{x\in U^c} B(x,\dfrac1n)$. Notice that $A_n$ is open and its complement $A_n^c$ (which is closed) is contained in $U$. To finish off the problem show that $U$ is the union of the $A_n^c$.

A set which is the union of countably many closed sets is called an $F_\sigma$ set. It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set) that every open set in a metric space is an $F_\sigma$ set.

Edit December 2023. I see I did not address the question whether every open set can be represented as the union of (any number of) closed sets. This is trivially true in every T<sub>1</sub> space (i.e. when every point is closed). Every set is the union if its one-point subsets (singletons) and each singleton is closed.
$A=\cup\{\{x\}:x\in A\}$, and each singleton $\{x\}$ is closed.

Comment: How can we see $U \subseteq \bigcup_n A_n^c$? I know $A_n^c$ is an increasing sequence, is it enough?

Comment: @MessiLio Not enough. But if $y\in U$ then since $U$ is open, there is some $n=n_y$ such that $B(y,\dfrac1n)\subseteq U.$ Then for any $x\in U^c$ we have $x\not\in B(y,\dfrac1n)$. Thus $y\not\in B(x,\dfrac1n)$, and $y\not\in A_n.$ Hence $y\in A_n^c.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be an open subset of a metric space $E$. If $U\ne E$ then
$$U=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\left\{x\in E:d(x,E\setminus U)\ge\frac1n\right\}$$
expresses $U$ as a countable union of closed sets.