# Is every generalized-$F_{\sigma}$ set an $F_{\sigma}$ set?

Tags: general-topology

A subset $S$ of a topological space $X$ is called a *generalized-$F_{\sigma}$ set* in $X$ if for all open $G \subset X$ with $S\subset G$, there exists an $F_{\sigma}$-set $F$ such that $S\subset F\subset G$.

It's easy to see that every $F_{\sigma}$-set is a generalized-$F_{\sigma}$ set, but I am not sure that every generalized-$F_{\sigma}$ set is a $F_{\sigma}$-set, and I can't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\omega_1$ with the order topology, and let $S$ be a [stationary subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_set) of $\omega_1$ that does not contain a closed, unbounded subset of $\omega_1$. It’s an easy consequence of the [pressing-down lemma (Fodor’s lemma)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor's_lemma) that if $U$ is an open nbhd of $S$, there is an $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $U\supseteq(\alpha,\omega_1)=[\alpha+1,\omega_1)$, and hence $U$ is itself an $F_\sigma$: it’s the union of the closed set $[\alpha+1,\omega_1)$ and the countably many closed singletons $\{\xi\}$ for $\xi\in U\cap[0,\alpha]$. Thus, $S$ is a generalized $F_\sigma$.

$S$ is not an $F_\sigma$, however, since its only closed subsets are bounded, hence countable, and $S$ itself is uncountable.

Comment: Thanks Brian very interesting counter-example

Comment: @Israel: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that [in a metric space all open sets are F<sub>σ</sub>](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1546336). It follows that every subset $S$ of a metric space is a generalised-F<sub>σ</sub> (given an open $G$ including $S$ take the witnessing F<sub>σ</sub>-set to be $G$ itself).

So a counterexample would be any subset of a metric space which is not F<sub>σ</sub>; e.g., [the set of irrational numbers in the real line](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69451).

Comment: This gets to the heart of the matter. Excellent

Comment: @ox69 0105: oh!! your counter-example is very cool!!!
thanks